# PowerShell, [Console]::KeyAvailable generates error when running as a background task

Tags: powershell, console, keypress, start-process

Instead of using `pause` in scripts, it is useful to me to make a script auto-exit after a set time. This is particularly useful to me as  various of these scripts can run interactively or as a background task with `Start-Process -WindowStyle Hidden` where a `pause` would mean that process could hang around forever, but with the timer, even if it's in the background, it will time out. I was given this solution via this question: [PowerShell, break out of a timer with custom keypress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74221559/powershell-break-out-of-a-timer-with-custom-keypress)

```
$t = 8; Write-Host "Exiting in $t seconds (press any key to exit now)" -NoNewLine
for ($i=0; $i -le $t; $i++) {
    Start-Sleep 1; Write-Host -NoNewLine "."
    if ([Console]::KeyAvailable) { 
        $key = [Console]::ReadKey($true).Key
        if ($key) { break }
    }
}
```

However, if I run this with `Start-Process -WindowStyle Hidden` in the background, PowerShell generates an error due to `[Console]::KeyAvailable` as there is no console available when running in the background.

```
Cannot see if a key has been pressed when either application does not have a 
console or when console input has been redirected from a file. Try 
Console.In.Peek.
At C:\Users\Boss\Install Chrome.ps1:36 char:78
+ ... ep 1;  Write-Host -NoNewLine "."; if ([Console]::KeyAvailable) { $key ...
+                                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], InvalidOperationExcept 
   ion
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.InvalidOperationException
```

• Is there some way that I can adjust the code I have such that it will not generate an error when run in the background, while still retaining the "press any key to exit now" option when run interactively?

• What does `Try Console.In.Peek` mean?

Comment: As for `Console.In.Peek`: It refers to [`[Console]::In`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Console.In), the current console's _stdin stream_, whose [`.Peek()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.textreader.peek) method allows you to read a pending character without consuming it (without removing it from the stream). As such it, it is (roughly) the stream-related analog to the console-related `[Console]::KeyAvailable` property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- **It is *not* [`Start-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process) that is the problem**:

  - When a *console application* is launched on Windows, such as `powershell.exe`, a console is *always* allocated - even if it is *hidden* (`-WindowStyle Hidden`)
  - Unless you use `-RedirectStandardInput`, that console's stdin stream (`[Console]::In`) is *not* redirected, as reflected in `[Console]::IsInputRedirected` returning `$false`.
  - Thus, your code would work: `[Console]::KeyAvailable` would always return `$false`, and the full timeout period would elapse.
- However, **you *would* see the problem with [`Start-Job`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/start-job)**:

  - The background [job](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Jobs) that is created uses a hidden PowerShell *child process* to run the code in the background, and the way that the calling PowerShell instance communicates with it is *via stdin*.
  - Thus, `[Console]::KeyAvailable` causes the statement-terminating error you saw, given that one of the causes mentioned in the error message applies: *stdin is redirected* (but a console does exist).

---

**Workarounds**:

Simply make the use of `[Console]::KeyAvailable` conditional on `[Console]::IsInputRedirected` returning `$false`:

```
$t = 8; Write-Host "Exiting in $t seconds (press any key to exit now)" -NoNewLine
for ($i=0; $i -le $t; $i++) {
    Start-Sleep 1; Write-Host -NoNewLine "."
    # Note the use of -not [Console]::IsInputRedirected
    if (-not [Console]::IsInputRedirected -and [Console]::KeyAvailable) { 
        $key = [Console]::ReadKey($true).Key
        if ($key) { break }
    }
}
```

**Alternatively**, use your code as-is and **use a *thread* job** instead, using **[`Start-ThreadJob`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/threadjob/start-threadjob)**, which *comes with PowerShell (Core) 7+* and in *Windows PowerShell* can be *installed on demand* with, e.g., `Install-Module ThreadJob -Scope CurrentUser`:

```
Start-ThreadJob { & 'C:\Users\Boss\Install Chrome.ps1' }
```

Thread jobs, if available, are generally preferable to regular, child-process-based background jobs, due to being faster and more light-weight.

Since the use of *stdin* only applies to *inter-process* communication, `[Console]::KeyAvailable` doesn't cause an error in a thread job, and - commendably - only pays attention to key strokes when the thread at hand is the *foreground* thread.

Answer (score 1):

Use a [`Runspace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.runspaces.runspace?view=powershellsdk-7.0.0) instead of [`Start-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process?view=powershell-7.3). Runspaces can be associated with your [`PSHost`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.host.pshost?view=powershellsdk-7.3.0) hence you would see both benefits, the output to your console and the ability to press any key to cancel your script.

```bash
try {
    $ttl = 20
    $iss = [initialsessionstate]::CreateDefault2()
    $rs  = [runspacefactory]::CreateRunspace($Host, $iss)
    $rs.Open()

    $ps  = [powershell]::Create().AddScript({
        param($ttl)

        Write-Host "Exiting in $ttl seconds (press any key to exit now)" -NoNewLine
        for ($i=0; $i -le $ttl; $i++) {
            Start-Sleep 1; Write-Host -NoNewLine "."
            if ([Console]::KeyAvailable) {
                $key = [Console]::ReadKey($true).Key
                if ($key) { break }
            }
        }
        Write-Host "Finished!" -ForegroundColor Green

    }).AddParameter('ttl', $ttl)

    $ps.Runspace = $rs
    $async       = $ps.BeginInvoke()

    do {
        $id = [System.Threading.WaitHandle]::WaitAny($async.AsyncWaitHandle, 200)
    }
    while($id -eq [System.Threading.WaitHandle]::WaitTimeout)

    $ps.Stop()
    $ps.EndInvoke($async)
}
finally {
    $ps, $rs | ForEach-Object Dispose
}
```

Comment: This is so useful, thanks, but I think the other answer more directly solves the approach that I wanted.